# Parse several urls in an array with PHP

Tags: php, parsing, web, browser

I've coded a PHP code that retrieves some data from an url. It first download the HTML and then parses some data.

The thing is that I've to run it with >20k different urls. Is there a way to do this running the PHP from a browser? How should I run a PHP long process?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use cUrl to download several urls at the same time, this would make your code to run faster:

https://www.phpied.com/simultaneuos-http-requests-in-php-with-curl/

I am not sure if it can request 20k+ urls at the same time, but you can run it in batches, if necessary. Run 1k times the function requesting 20 websites at the same time is faster than requesting 20k websites one by one. :)

I did not understand the part of running the PHP from a browser. PHP runs only in the server. You could download it, install it in your computer e runs from there, is it that you want?

Comment: Sorry, I think I have not explained myself very well. I said running from a browser because I'm calling the PHP from a browser (i.e. mywebsite/parser.php). The thing is that the webpage that it's loading my results crashes. I think it can be a kind of timeout for long requests.... Any idea of how I should deal with this?

Maybe instead of PHP I should use Python?

Comment: Hum... What kind of error does it shows? Would it be out of memory? Does it just freezes the browser?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PHP Command line](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php) :

> Tell PHP to execute a certain file.
>
> ```
> $ php my_script.php
> ```

from [PHP Command line usage](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.usage.php).